# Dynamicly inject content with ajax / but with php instead of html

Tags: php, ajax

Been building sites with this code from chris coyier recently.  Ajax jquery .load() etc.

everything is working great.

see code dump here http://css-tricks.com/dynamic-page-replacing-content/

```
$(function() {

var newHash      = "",
    $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
    $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
    baseHeight   = 0,
    $el;

$pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

$("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
    window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
    return false;
});

$(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

    newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

    if (newHash) {
        $mainContent
            .find("#guts")
            .fadeOut(200, function() {
                $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                    $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                        $pageWrap.animate({
                            height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                        });
                    });
                    $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                    $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
                });
            });
    };

});

$(window).trigger('hashchange');

});
```

HOWEVER - I have now been turning all my pages into php - and I can't seem to hack it together... I thought I could just change the "html" to "php"  in the jQuery...  but that is not working...

Any help ?

Comment: uhm, in the example he also uses PHP.. But it shouldn't be a problem anyway so I think your problem lies elsewhere

Comment: By "not working" what do you mean? Is it displaying the php code as html or is some other error occurring?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to waste your time guys - I had been in front of this computer an unhealthy amount of time.

I had rushed and replaced href with php ... (thinking it was html)

REMEMBER TO TAKE BREAKS EVERYONE - OR FACE LOOKING LIKE A FOOL (Like me)

-thanks for your time...